# CSS: How do I add a mobile hover effect on a button tap?

Tags: css, html-email

How would I go about adding styling when a user taps on a button via mobile for gmail and outlook? My goal is to have the user know that they tapped the button on mobile.

Comment: Try this selector `button:active`

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways of achieving this by using a tag.
First one use a:target

```
    a {
      padding: 10px;
      background: green;
    }

   a:target {
      background: red;
    }
```

Second one is using a:visited

```
   a {
      padding: 10px;
      background: green;
    }

   a:visited {
      background: red;
    }
```